# How to handle Transaction in Nested procedure in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 proc i.e.  Proc1 and Proc2.
I am executing proc1 inside proc2. There are multiple DML operation in both procedure. output of proc1 is used in proc2 for DML operation.
if Error occurred in proc2 then
 how to handle transaction in both proc for rollback all DML operation?

Should I write transaction in both proc?

Comment: There are no nested transactions in SQL Server. Start transaction in the outer proc, call the inner proc from a `try` block and roll back on a `catch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a generic error handler procedure based on http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html that we - when applicable - include in our (nested) transactions to ensure the chain is managed properly:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ErrorHandler](@caller VARCHAR(255))
AS BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @errmsg NVARCHAR(2048), @severity TINYINT, @state TINYINT, @errno INT, @lineno INT;
    SELECT @errmsg=REPLACE(ERROR_MESSAGE(), 'DatabaseException: ', 'DatabaseException: '+QUOTENAME(@caller)+' --> ')
         , @severity=ERROR_SEVERITY()
         , @state=ERROR_STATE()
         , @errno=ERROR_NUMBER()
         , @lineno=ERROR_LINE();
    IF @errmsg NOT LIKE 'DatabaseException%' BEGIN
        SELECT @errmsg=N'DatabaseException: '+QUOTENAME(@caller)+N', Line '+LTRIM(STR(@lineno))+N', Error '+LTRIM(STR(@errno))+N': '+@errmsg;
    END;
    RAISERROR('%s', @severity, @state, @errmsg);
END;
```

(Compiled in the master database and marked as system procedure)

We use this error handler as follows. In the demo I have an outer proc and an inner proc both using a transaction.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspOuterProc
AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  EXEC dbo.uspInnerProc;

  PRINT 1;

  COMMIT;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@trancount > 0
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

  EXEC master.dbo.sp_ErrorHandler @caller = 'dbo.uspOuterProc';
  END CATCH;
  END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspInnerProc
AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  PRINT 2;

  SELECT 1 / 0;

  PRINT 3;

  COMMIT;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@trancount > 0
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

  EXEC master.dbo.sp_ErrorHandler @caller = 'dbo.uspInnerProc';
  END CATCH;
  END;
GO
```

After you compile this and run:

```
EXEC dbo.uspOuterProc
```

You should get this result:

```
2

Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_ErrorHandler, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 48]
DatabaseException: [dbo.uspOuterProc] --> [dbo.uspInnerProc], Line 12, Error 8134: Divide by zero error encountered.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the transaction in the outer procedure ( in your case proc2). If any error will be occurred in proc1 it will be taken care of by proc2 transaction handler.
Am assuming that proc1 will not be called directly, it will be called inside the proc2.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 basic transaction handling statements (and a few advanced ones I'm not gonna mention):

- **`BEGIN TRANSACTION`**: Will raise the `@@TRANCOUNT` session variable by 1. If it goes from 0 to 1 then this marks the start of a transaction. Any value higher than 1 will keep the same transaction ongoing.
- **`COMMIT`**: Will lower the `@@TRANCOUNT` session variable by 1. If it goes from 1 to 0 then the transaction is marked as finished and will impact all changes done since it was first created.
- **`ROLLBACK`**: Will decrease the `@@TRANCOUNT` session variable to 0 (whichever it's value was), as long as it was at least 1 or higher. This will close the transaction and revert all changes done since it was first created.

Nested transactions are a bunch of `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statements put together. The only point where the transaction gets fully commited and the changes are made permanent is when there is a `COMMIT` that lowers the transaction count from 1 to 0. That means you need one `COMMIT` for each `BEGIN TRANSACTION` you executed, like a pyramid.

Check the following example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT @@TRANCOUNT -- 1

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT @@TRANCOUNT -- 2

COMMIT TRANSACTION

SELECT @@TRANCOUNT -- 1 (no change is permanent yet, not even the last one)

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT @@TRANCOUNT -- 2

ROLLBACK

SELECT @@TRANCOUNT -- 0 (all changes were discarded)
```

When you have an SP that executes another SP and both have their transactions, the only thing you need to care about is to `CATCH` errors and do the proper `ROLLBACK` **IF** there's an open/active transaction ongoing (if not the `ROLLBACK` statement will fail saying that there is nothing to rollback).

A very basic `CATCH` would be like the following:

```
BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        /* Do some operations */

        /* Execute another SP that might have the following:

        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            -- Some other operations

        COMMIT

        */

    COMMIT

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

    DECLARE @v_ErrorMessage VARCHAR(MAX) = ERROR_MESSAGE()

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 -- Only rollback if there is an active transaction
        ROLLBACK

    RAISERROR (@v_ErrorMessage, 16, 1)

END CATCH
```

You can read [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82681/how-to-rollback-when-3-stored-procedures-are-started-from-one-stored-procedure) if you want to delve deeply into the best way for handling transactions on SQL Server.