# Will all transaction in this stored procedure be rolled back

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, rollback

I have created a stored procedure (shown below) in SQL Server and tried to include a Rollback Transaction as I need to have a "stored procedure that has a transaction around it, so that if/when it fails all inserts will be rolled back."

I am unsure if this work or not, or will work, I cannot test yet as only developing locally, but wondered if someone wouldn't mind looking over the Rollback Transaction part of the stored procedure and advise if on the right path?

```
USE AutomatedTesting
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertTestCases] 
    (@AddedTFS INT,
     @Scenario NVARCHAR(500),
     @TargetTableName NVARCHAR(100),
     @TargetFieldName NVARCHAR(100),
     @ExpectedResult NVARCHAR(100),
     @TargetTableDBName NVARCHAR(100),
     @TargetTableSchema NVARCHAR(100),
     @TargetFieldIsDateTime NVARCHAR(1),
     @TestCaseIdentifiers dbo.TestCaseIdentifiers READONLY )  -- can only be READONLY. meaning you cannot amend the param
     /* @TestCaseIdentifiers var will be prepopulated
        TestDataIdentifiersNEW is a custom data type which has  fields (TestSequence ColumnName ColumnValue IsAlphaNumeric)

        so stored procedure is called like:
        EXEC [dbo].[spTest_UserDefinedDatatype] 'param1','param2' @temp_testdata 

        @temp_testdata  will already be defined and popualted(INSERT INTO ) before exec to add in 1 to many rows.
        for example:
        ColumnName  ColumnValue
        PATIENTID   123456
        SOURCESYS   PAS

        in simple terms above EXEC is:
        EXEC [dbo].[spTest_UserDefinedDatatype] 'param1','param2'   'PATIENTID  123456'
                                                                    'SOURCESYS  PAS'
    */
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
        BEGIN
            --DECLARE @TableNameUpdate SYSNAME = @TargetTableName
            --DECLARE @CDI SYSNAME = REPLACE(@TargetTableName,'CDO','CDI')  -- so if targettablename param is CDO then swap it to CDI.  why?

            DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '  INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestCasesIdentifier] ([TestCaseId], [TestCaseSequence], [FieldName], [FieldValue], [AlphaNumeric]) VALUES '

            DECLARE @i INT = 1
            DECLARE @TableNameUpdate SYSNAME = @TargetTableName
            DECLARE @CDI SYSNAME = REPLACE(@TargetTableName,'CDO','CDI')
            DECLARE @ColName SYSNAME
            DECLARE @Ret NVARCHAR(256)
            DECLARE @sql2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
            DECLARE @TestCaseID INT = -1   --does this need default variable?
            DECLARE @ErrorCode INT = @@error
            DECLARE @TestSequence INT
            DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
            DECLARE @ColumnValue VARCHAR(100)
            DECLARE @IsAlphaNumeric BIT
            DECLARE @TableTestSequence INT =  ISNULL((SELECT MAX([TableTestSequence]) + 1 FROM TestCases WHERE @TargetTableName = [TargetTableName]), 1)

            -- INSERT into TestCases.   1 record

            -- An assumption that a number of fields will have defaults on them -            if not, extra fields will need adding
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestCases] ([AddedTFS], [TableTestSequence], [Scenario], 
                                           [TargetTableName], [TargetFieldName], [ExpectedResult],
                                           [TargetTableDBName], [TargetTableSchema], [TargetFieldIsDateTime])
            VALUES (@AddedTFS,      -- AddedTFS (The TFS Number of the Development carried out)
                    ISNULL((SELECT MAX([TableTestSequence]) + 1     -- TableTestSequence (Generates the next Sequence Number for a Table)
                            FROM TestCases                          -- if table doesnt exist in TestCases then sets to 1
                            WHERE @TargetTableName = [TargetTableName]), 1),
                    @Scenario,                                  -- Scenario (A description of the scenario use GIVEN and WHERE)
                    @TargetTableName,                           -- TargetTableName (References the Target Table entered at the top of this SQL - SET @TableName = 'CDO_APC_ELECTIVE_ADMISSION_LIST')
                    @TargetFieldName,                                   -- TargetFieldName (The Field in which we want to test)
                    @ExpectedResult,                                    -- ExpectedResult (The expected output/result of the field in which we want to test)
                    @TargetTableDBName,                             -- The DB to be used
                    @TargetTableSchema,                             -- the schema to be used
                    @TargetFieldIsDateTime)                         ---- 1 = Yes, 0 = No (Is Target field a datetime field) 

            -- Grab the identity value just generated by the last statement and the last error code generated
            -- in order to reference TestCases PK when adding to TestCaseIdentifiers
            SELECT @TestCaseID = SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @ErrorCode = @@error

            IF @ErrorCode = 0 --OR @TestCaseID <> -1      -- @ErrorCode <> 0  if error then back out testcases INSERT?  surely should use BEGIN/ROLLBACK tran
            --IF @ErrorCode = 0 OR @TestCaseID <> -1
            -- If there was no error creating the TestCase record, create the records for the WHERE clause
            BEGIN
                /*
                 rollback insert if no matching records
                 rollback insert if SQL returns more than 1 record
                 return error message to user
                */
                SELECT 
                    ic.index_column_id, c.name
                INTO #tmp
                FROM sys.indexes i
                JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON i.object_id = ic.object_id 
                                          AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
                JOIN sys.columns c ON c.column_id = ic.column_id 
                                   AND c.object_id = ic.object_id
                JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
                WHERE t.name = @CDI
                  AND i.is_primary_key = 1

        IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TestCaseIdentifiers) = 0
        --IF @PKValues IS NULL
        BEGIN

            WHILE @i <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp)
            BEGIN
                   SELECT @ColName = [name]
                   FROM   #tmp
                   WHERE  index_column_id = @i

                   -- if @expectedvalue IS NULL
                   SET @sql2 = 'SELECT TOP 1 @RetvalOut = ' + QUOTENAME(@ColName) + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@CDI) + ' ORDER BY NEWID()'
                   -- else
                   -- SET @sql2 = ''

                   EXECUTE sp_executesql @command = @sql2, @ParmDefinition = N'@RetvalOut NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT', @retvalOut = @Ret OUTPUT

                   SET @sql += '(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),@TestCaseID) + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@i) + ',''' + @ColName + ''',''' + @Ret + ''',1),'

                   SET @i+=1


    SELECT @sql = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@sql),2,8000))

    PRINT @sql
    EXEC @sql

            END
        END

    ELSE


    BEGIN
--PRINT 'got here'
        DECLARE csr_TestCaseIdentifierInsert CURSOR FOR
            SELECT  [TestSequence],[ColumnName],[ColumnValue],[IsAlphaNumeric]
            FROM @TestCaseIdentifiers
            ORDER BY [TestSequence]

            OPEN csr_TestCaseIdentifierInsert

                FETCH NEXT FROM csr_TestCaseIdentifierInsert INTO @TestSequence, @ColumnName, @ColumnValue, @IsAlphaNumeric
                WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
                BEGIN

                    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TestCasesIdentifier] 
                    ([TestCaseId], 
                    [TestCaseSequence], 
                    [FieldName], 
                    [FieldValue], 
                    [AlphaNumeric])
                    VALUES 
                    (@TestCaseID,  @TestSequence, @ColumnName, @ColumnValue,@IsAlphaNumeric)
                    FETCH NEXT FROM csr_TestCaseIdentifierInsert INTO @TestSequence, @ColumnName, @ColumnValue, @IsAlphaNumeric
                END
            CLOSE csr_TestCaseIdentifierInsert
            DEALLOCATE csr_TestCaseIdentifierInsert


    END -- loop to add records to testcasesidentifier
END
END
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN

        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT = ERROR_STATE()

    -- Use RAISERROR inside the CATCH block to return error  
    -- information about the original error that caused  
    -- execution to jump to the CATCH block.  
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState);
END CATCH
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sql-server - done the change thanks for the heads up

Comment: Why can't you test developing locally? Is it that you don't a local SQL instance or container? I would expect the code to rollback the transaction, although I suggest you add `SET XACT_ABORT ON` (a best practice in procs with explict transactions) and re-raise errors in the catch block using `THROW`: `IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;THROW;`

Comment: We do not have the tables locally as contain sensitive information. The intention is to create the SP locally and promote onto a Dev Server. Having never used BEGIN TRANSACTION I just google a bit and placed it where I thought it may sit, first attempt and all that. as long as the criteria "stored procedure that has a transaction around it, so that if/when it fails all inserts will be rolled back." is met then I'd be more than happy for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. I usually wrap the stored proc code within a `BEGIN..END` block as well, then next comes the most important part: you must add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` before your TRY..CATCH and `BEGIN TRAN`, as SQL Server defaults the `XACT_ABORT` to `OFF`. Otherwise not everything will be rolled back.
Example setup:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspMyTestProc
AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

  BEGIN TRY
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  -- Do your magic stuff here before committing...

  COMMIT;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
  IF @@trancount > 0
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

  -- Add extra error logging here if you want...

  END CATCH;
  END;
GO
```

Also, if you want to add a possible stacktrace if you are using nested procedures et cetera you might want to consider using a generic error handler à la Erland Sommerskog. We adapted this approach completely. See for more details [How to handle Transaction in Nested procedure in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54743355/how-to-handle-transaction-in-nested-procedure-in-sql-server/54744336#54744336)

Comment: I got the placing wrong needed to be all inside the first BEGIN and END, again thanks for the advice much appreciated, and a happy christmas